# How to create a pdf report from word template in Matlab

Tags: matlab

Is it possible to create a report in pdf format from a word template using report generator in Matlab R2018b?

The code I am using is below and creates the word report, but I would like to save it in pdf format instead:

```
import mlreportgen.dom.*

 D = Document('From Template','docx','Template.dotx');
 open(D);
     moveToNextHole(D)
     append(D,'Hello World')
 close(D);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, something like this is possible:

```
mlreportgen.dom.Document.createTemplate('mytemplate','pdf');
```

In your case, I would try,

```
import mlreportgen.dom.*

 D = Document('From Template','pdf','Template.dotx');
 open(D);
     moveToNextHole(D)
     append(D,'Hello World')
 close(D);
```

You can find more information [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/rptgen/ug/generate-a-report-using-a-template.html).

Comment: Hi Joey. Thanks I tried it bu get this error: Error using mlreportgen.dom.Document/open
Invalid template: Template.dotx

Comment: I would try without that 3rd argument. Can you try just with `D = Document('From Template','pdf');`. I don't know what this `Template.dotx` is or where it comes from.

Comment: If I leave the 3rd argument I get a blank pdf with only the "Hello World"

Comment: Ok, I read your question again. "*How to create a pdf report from word template in Matlab"*. You are not looking to just create a pdf. You want to create a pdf from a **Word Template**. This is NOT possible, unless you have `pdf` template also.

Comment: As per the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/rptgen/ug/create-report-container.html), *"The template type must match the document type."* which means a pdf template for a generating a pdf report.

Comment: Strange because it say "PDF (from Word)" in the https://se.mathworks.com/help/rptgen/ug/generate-a-report-using-a-template.html Do you know if it possible to create the pdftx (template) from a pdf file?

Comment: @Birch78, yes the documentation on two pages seems to contradict each other. On the page I referred to, it clearly states that the template must match the file type. I would try one more thing, `D = Document('From Template','pdf','Template');`. Maybe that works, otherwise, someone else here might be able to come up with some solution.